# More than 4MB response from IBM MQ in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

I am trying to run some load tests on jmeter by connecting to IBM MQ. It works fine except for a particular message which get a close to 5 MB response.

So, here's the setup, I push a message from jmeter to a request queue on IBM MQ. My was app picks it up and sends a response to the response queue where the JMETER picks it up. This setup works fine, till i send a particular message whose response is close to `5MB`.

The jmeter simply doesn't pick this response and that in turn holds up all the other messages on the response queue. 
I think the `default` recieve size for jmeter is `4MB`, but can i change it for MQ response in jmeter properties somewhere. 
I tried by making changes to `user.properties` and `jmeter.properties` in jmeter bin directory but nothing worked.

Comment: I have never heard of generic response size limit in JMeter. Which sampler are you using? How did you judge that it was not picked up? Did you check that JMeter did not OOM, doesn't have exceptions in log?

Comment: @Kiril S There are exceptions in the jmeter log. basically saying unable to pick messages `MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue`. I see the message sitting on the response queue. I am trying to use a JMS point to point sampler.

Comment: Yes, so this is probably a limitation or a bug of that particular sampler. Try to enable debug log and see if it says anything more explicit than a generic error `MQJMS2002 ` you are getting. If I had this issue, I'd also dig into source code to see how it's implemented (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/jms/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/). That often gives you clues on what could be the cause. And I would still look at the JVM memory to make sure it's not a simple OOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception thrown is related to MQJMS. So check the linked exception for MQ reason code returned. If you are connecting to queue manager using a client mode connection, then check the MAXMSGL attribute of the Server Connection channel you are using. By default the MAXMSGL is set to 4 MB. You will need to increase the  attribute value to larger messages.